# Sort data using vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

```
Sub Macro4M()

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A2:A20"), _
        xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
        255, 0)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:P20")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm trying to sort the rows and columns where data doesnt exist but in the above code sorting operation is only applied from row A2:A20 and column A1:P20
My criteria is i want to apply sort for the entire row and column in Worksheet
Can anyone please help me out with this

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro4M()

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("A:A"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A:P")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```